# Chain stream providers in riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Is it possible to chain two or more StreamProviders in riverpod?

I have a stream provider wired up to a socket:

```
final marketChangesProvider = StreamProvider<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>((ref) async* {

    var socket = await MarketStream.subscribeToMarket(...);

    await for (final message in socket.map(decodeUint8List)) {
        yield message;
    }

  }
});
```

To decouple the transformations I want to make I was wondering if I could create different streams downstream for consumption, e.g.:

```
final changesTypeAProvider = StreamProvider<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>((ref) async* {


    final messages = ref.watch(marketChangesProvider);

    // ??? 
    // the following doesn't work
    messages.when(
        loading: () => null,
        error: (error, stackTrace) => null,
        data: (messages) {
            // Display all the messages in a scrollable list view.
            yield PriceCache();
        },
    );


});
```

Is this some anti-pattern for stream providers?

Not sure how to work out the mechanics for the second provider.

Comment: Both of these could be either AsyncNotifier or StreamNotifier.  You can always convert one to the other with riverpod.